# Failed to update MySQL database when the update method is called from different method

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am making an android app wehre I am trying to update user_group information in a MySQL database using PHP and JSON. The method I'm using is successfully updating the database the case where I call it from addHome(), but when the same method is called in my joinExistingHome() method, I am unable to add to the database...

Here are the important portions of my PHP code:

```
// include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
else if ($tag == "update") {
        $user_group = $_POST['user_group'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        //update user
        $user = $db->updateUser($user_group, $email);
        if ($user) {
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["user_group"] = $user["user_group"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Updating user group";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

/**
     *Updating a user's group
     */

    public function updateUser($user_group, $email) {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_group = '$user_group' WHERE email = '$email'");
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            //$uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is my java code where I try to update the database:

```
public void addHome() {
        //make a new dialog popup and user can enter a new group name.
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.set_home_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Add a new home");
        dialog.show();

        cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        submitButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submitGroup);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText groupName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.group);
                final String name = groupName.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("Name of group is: " + name);
                if (groupNames.contains(name)) {
                    System.out.println("The group already exists please enter a new group name");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("Trying to update user group");

                addGroupToDatabases(name);
            }
        });
        //System.out.println("here2");
    }

    public void joinExistingHome() {
        //new dialog appears and prompt user to enter existing group name
        //make a new dialog popup and user can enter a new group name.
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.set_home_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Enter existing home");
        dialog.show();


        cancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        submitButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.submitGroup);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //need to check if the groupname is in sqlite database.
                EditText groupName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.group);
                final String name = groupName.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("available groups: " + groupNames);
                if (name != null && groupNames.contains(name) && !name.isEmpty()) {

                    addGroupToDatabases(name);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No group with group name: " + name + " exists");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addGroupToDatabases(final String name) {
        if (!name.isEmpty()) {
            //add to sqlite database
            //updateUser(name);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        String tag_string_req = "req_update";

        //showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Update Response: " + response.toString());
                //hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        System.out.println("User group successfully updated in mysql");
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The use group failed to update");
                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Update Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            String email = db.getUserDetails().get("email");

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                System.out.println("trying to return params");
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("tag", "update");
                params.put("user_group", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                System.out.println("User's email is: " + email);
                return params;
            }
        };
        System.out.println("updating group to mysql database");
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
//                System.out.println("here1");
//                System.out.println("user group: " + db.getUserDetails().get("user_group"));
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Is `$db` still accessible in this method? Why not call `$this->updateUser()`?

Comment: The "important part of your php code." I have no idea what is calling your first block of code. Is that residing in a function within that same class? There's not much context for me to go off of.

Comment: I need to store the response of updateUser() so I can pass it back in JSON form to add to a SQLite database.

Comment: `$user = $db->updateUser($user_group, $email);` wouldn't work if `$db` isn't in scope. If that code snippet is in another function within the class where you define the `updateUser()` function, you can call it withi `$this->updateUser()`

Comment: Inside of my addHome() and joinExistingHome() I call addGroupToDatabases(), which calls the php code.

Comment: The php code works for addHome(), but not joinExistingHome(), but I don't understand why because I'm calling the same method in both.

Comment: And yes, $db is in scope.

Comment: Don't have enough of your PHP code to tell if `$db` is still in scope or how you're instantiating it. Possibly include that entire function for context.

Comment: Okay I added it. The function updateUser($user_group, $email) is in DB_Functions.php, which I did not include- I just put the function I used in my question.

Comment: Are you certain that `$tag` is what you're expecting and you're not running into some spelling or logic error?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct tag- it is going into the right method- i'm getting the error: $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Updating user group";

Comment: Try to `var_dump($result)` and see what is happening. Is it failing to create a mysql_connection? I'd definitely debug that part out.